# How to update mongodb document

Tags: php, mongodb, updates

Hi i'm really mongodb newbie.

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("53182e32e4b0feedb1dea751"),
    "solutions": [
        [
            {
                "solution": "Double Room Economy (Without Breakfast)",
                "board": "Room Only",
                "id": "HK-15501871",
                "price": 5000,
                "available": "1",
                "CXL": "[]",
                "unique": 0
            },
            {
                "solution": "Double Room Economy (With Breakfast)",
                "board": "Room Only",
                "id": "HK-15501871",
                "price": 4600,
                "available": "1",
                "CXL": "[]",
                "unique": 1
            },
            {
                "solution": "Double Room Economy (Room Only)",
                "board": "Room Only",
                "id": "HK-15501871",
                "price": 5500,
                "available": "1",
                "CXL": "[]",
                "unique": 2
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And i need to update the field `CXL` inside the second array of `solutions`.
so solutions.1.CXL

This is how i take document:

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$query      = array("_id"=>new MongoId($id));       
$document   = $collection->findOne($query);
```

now i need to update that field without touch the other.

How can i do?

Thanks!

**SOLVED THANKS TO @Sammaye**

i solved in this way:

```
$collection->update(
    array('_id' => new MongoId('..')),
    array('$set' => array('solutions.0.1.CXL' => 'something'))
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

To actually update by the first index then you can do:

```
$db->collection->update(
    ['_id' => new \MongoId($id)],
    ['$set' => ['solutions.0.1.CLX' => 'whatever']]
);
```

I misread the question in posting the information below:

So what you wanna update all CXL fields in the document (since you are only searching by top level document `_id`)?

That isn't possible without manually pulling this document out and iterating the subdocuments in the `solutions` field and then resaving it.

This is becausde there is currently no way of saying, "Update all that match"

This, however, is most likely the JIRA you would want to look for: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Comment: No, i don't want to update ALL CXL field but just a specific one. In the example i want to update CXL in the object with index 1

Comment: @JackTurky agreed. The question was misread. There is an answer I submitted along with the explaination for your benefit.

Comment: @JackTurky CLX is a string not an array, do you mena it to be an array?

Comment: sorry.. using                                                   $collection->update(
    array('_id' => new MongoId('..')),
    array('$set' => array('solutions.0.1.CLX' => 'something'))
); it edit all document changing it in solutions[0][1][CXL]="something" deleting me all other fields

Comment: @JackTurky hmm I gotta test that, it shouldn't be the case, I use this query myself

Comment: @JackTurky What is the result after running this function? Does it update multiple documents or is just that it is removing something?

Comment: sorry! i made mistake! :(

Comment: @JackTurky heh np we all do it :)

Answer (score 3):

As long as you **know** you are going to update the second element then use the index of the array to do so. But that problem next. First you need the $set operator in order not to blow away your document and just set the field value:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("53182e32e4b0feedb1dea751") },
    { $set: { "solutions.0.1.CXL": [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
)
```

If you just want to **add** to the array rather than replace the whole thing, then just use $push instead:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("53182e32e4b0feedb1dea751") },
    { $push: { "solutions.0.1.CXL": 4 } }
)
```

If you are paying attention to the notation, then you will notice that the array index values are present in the field to be updated. There is a very good reason for this, which can be read on the documentation for the [positional $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator.

The issue is that you have a nested array, which as the documentation refers to, causes a problem if you try to match items within that nested array. That problem is, if you try to use the "positional" operator to find the matched index of something you look for in a query, then it will contain the value of the **first** array index match that it finds.

In this case that would be your "top level" array and the "found" index is `0` and not `1` as you may expect.

Please be aware of this issue if you intend to use nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can update like this:

```
update({ 
       _id: ObjectId("53182e32e4b0feedb1dea751"), 
       solutions.id: HK-15501871,
       solutions.CLX: "Whatever!",")
   },{
       $set: {"comments.$.type": abc}
   }, false, true
);
```

You may want to go through this once

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: The positional $ operator will not work here as the matching array index will be that of the **top** level array. In this case that will be `0` and the index that is wanted is `1`. The reason is explained in the answer I submitted, along with the documentation link.